# sentence formation and use of right grammar

Tags: sentence

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

*Her bank account was opened under me as a guardian.*

Actually I need to say that when her account was opened I had to be her guardian since she was considered minor.

Is there a better way to say the above?

Comment: "When her account was opened I had to act as her guardian since she was considered minor" is an answer that is almost in your question.

Comment: If you want to use ***under*** you could say *Her bank account was opened **under my guardianship***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things like accounts and owner title are not held under people, but under or in their *names*.

> The mortgage is in my wife's name, but paid out of our joint account.
>
> I have a reservation for 4 under Smith.

It is not quite clear in whose name this account has been opened. If your name is on it but you opened it for her behalf, you could say

> Her bank account was opened under my name, as guardian.

If her name is on it, you could simply say, as Tushar has given,

> Her bank account was opened with me as guardian.

If the opening of the bank account is not your main focus, but rather your fiduciary obligations, I would reword it to say

> I am listed/named/recorded as guardian of her bank account.

Answer (score 1):

Her bank account was opened ***with*** me (acting) as (a) guardian.